# Extract text from Online image Url In python

Tags: python, python-tesseract, text-extraction

I have written code based on the references found on web and some youtube videos but it doesnt seem to work for me and i am not understanding any further what could be the issue .

```
import io
import requests
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

r = requests.get("http://www.teamjimmyjoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Classic-Best-Funny-Text-Messages-earthquake-titties.jpg",stream=True)
# print( type(response) ) # <class 'requests.models.Response'>

img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content))
# print( type(img) ) # <class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(text)
```

i am getting this error

```
  File "F:\Projects\FileExtractor\untitled3.py", line 16, in <module>
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2943, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001E85C0BAA40>
```

please help me with this issue .
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a further thought.  Why not spoof the browser headers, this now appears to work.

```
import io
import requests
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

url = 'http://www.teamjimmyjoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Classic-Best-Funny-Text-Messages-earthquake-titties.jpg'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content))
# # print( type(img) ) # <class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
#
print(text)
```

Response is:

```
Hey! | just saw on CNN

there was an earthquake
near you. Are you ok?

 

| Yes! We're all fine!

What did it rate.on the titty
scale?

| Well they only jiggled a |

 

little bit, so probably not

that high.

HAHAHAHAHAHA | LOVE
YOU

Richter scale. My phone is |
a 12 yr old boy.

—————————r
```

Comment: Running this script gives me nothing but blankin spyder terminal for some reason which i dont understand !!@Johnny John Boy

Comment: I'm using virtualenv, but it definitely works.  I had to install tesseract to test though but even before I did I got an error thrown saying it wasn't installed. 100% works.

Comment: Be awesome if you can mark it as correct as it does work.

Comment: i executed this code in jupyter and it worked like a charm but not in spyder !! @Johnny John Boy

Answer (score 1):

Always start with the most simple fix first and work up from there.

```
import requests
# import pytesseract
# from PIL import Image

r = requests.get("http://www.teamjimmyjoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Classic-Best-Funny-Text-Messages-earthquake-titties.jpg",stream=True)

print(r.text)
```

Yields this result:

```
<head><title>Not Acceptable!</title></head><body><h1>Not Acceptable!</h1><p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.</p></body></html>
```

The problem is you are not downloading the image, you're being blocked by Mod_Security.  You need to overcome that before you can get the image and therefore the text.